# jQuery Datatables acts weird with radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button, datatables

I use jQuery Datatables for styling a table.
One column of the table contains radio buttons.

```
<td class="image">
                <input type="radio" name="11" value="a" onclick="updateStatus('11', 'a')" /><img src="/jwz/images/icons/a.png" name="a" alt="a" title="Activeer account" />
                <input type="radio" name="11" value="b" onclick="updateStatus('11', 'b')" /><img src="/jwz/images/icons/b.png" name="b" alt="b" title="Ban account" />
                <input type="radio" name="11" value="w" checked="checked" onclick="updateStatus('11', 'w')" /><img src="/jwz/images/icons/w.png" name="w" alt="w" title="Zet account in de wacht"/>

            </td>
```

The thing is that the checked attribute doesn't work for the first row of the table. In all other rows one of the buttons is checked, but not in the first row.  When I disable jQuery Datatables it works all fine. So, jQuery Datatables is the problem.

Can someone help me with a solution of workaround?

Comment: Pretty hard to help like this. Could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with relevant code that reproduces the problem ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ptY6B/3/ See ID 10. Its the first row in the original html. jQuery put it on the third place. When I delete the last 3 colums, it works fine, i discovered.

Comment: @OrangeTux i edited your fiddle and now seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/ptY6B/4/

Comment: @nicolaPeluchetti What have you changed, besides deleting some columns?

Comment: i deleted the script tags (You must not use them), choose jQuery as the framwork to use and deleted the row                 `"aoColumnDefs": [
                    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4, 5 ] } 
                ]` that caused an error becuase datatable was expecting 6 columns and you gave only one

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not update the file. So we were talking about the wrong code. Here is the right link, http://jsfiddle.net/ptY6B/6/ Look at ID 10, no radio button is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where a radiobuttonlist in the first row of my jQuery DataTable was not displaying the selected radio button as checked when the page was loaded; despite checked="checked" being applied on the radio input when inspecting the HTML.

When binding my table, I now add a class ("radioButtonToCheck") to the first radioButtonList's selected listitem (in C#):

```
 listItem.Attributes["class"] = "radioButtonToCheck";
```

Then the jQuery DataTable fnDrawCallback is used to redraw that radio button's checked status.

```
var roomReportingTable = $('.horizontalScroll table').dataTable({
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                    // first radio button list selection is not rendered, so needs to be re-drawn
                    $('.radioButtonToCheck input').attr("checked", "checked");
                }
            });
```

More information on jQuery DataTables fnDrawCallback: http://datatables.net/faqs#ss_events